# javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to use LDAP search but getting error as below.

```
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); 
remaining name 'dc=internal,dc=<name>,dc=com'
```

Below is my code simple

```
LdapContext ctx=new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
SearchControls sc = new SearchControls(scope, countlim, timelim, attrs, retobj, deref);
NamingEnumeration ne = ctx.search(usersContainer, filter,sc);
while (ne.hasMore())
{
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) ne.next();
    //Other business Logic
}
```

On more debugging I can find that after processing last element from group it's throwing error while trying to get in while loop.

For my filter criteria I have 6 member in group and in printing it's printing upto 6 members data and then throwing that exception.

On some threads I can see, it's asking to set `ignorePartialResultExcepton = true` but can't get which methods need to pass the same.

Anyone can help on this.